# How to create Poll Question programmatically with multiple answer choices in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, polls

The code below does not create the choices directly.

```
$poll = Poll::create(array(
  'id' => 'poll',
  'uid' => '1',
  'question' => 'What is your favorite color?',
  'choice' => entity_create('poll_choice', array(
    'id' => 'poll_choice',
    'label' => 'choice',
    'langcode' => 'en',
    'choice' => array('Red' , 'Blue'),  // this line do not help me to create multiple option for choice.
  )),
  'anonymous_vote_allow' => '1',
  'result_vote_allow' => '1',
  'status' => '1',
));
 $poll->save();
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Your question is not clear. If you are showing code that works, what code do you want?

Comment: The question is in the title and the provided code does *not* work. I suppose that could be more obvious, but it can be answered just fine if you know poll module . Which I do ;)

Comment: @Berdir If you do know Poll module, why don't you help him?

Comment: The question is on hold, so it can't be answered :) As I said, the question is clear enough for me, not sure what else to add. Choices aren't correctly created.